# Android Studio starts fail with "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.swing.UIManager"

Tags: java, android, swing

android-studio-bundle-133.970939:

```
java version "1.5.0"
gij (GNU libgcj) version 4.8.1 20130909 [gcc-4_8-branch revision 202388]

Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.swing.UIManager
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.14)
   at javax.swing.UIManager.getUI(libgcj.so.14)
   at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.updateUI(libgcj.so.14)
   at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.<init>(libgcj.so.14)
   at javax.swing.JEditorPane.<init>(libgcj.so.14)
   at javax.swing.JTextPane.<init>(libgcj.so.14)
   at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:216)
   at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:203)
   at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:86)
```

with openSUSE 13.1, x86_64, Oracle JDK 7u51

Comment: Is JDK 7 in your `PATH`? see also [*SDB:Installing Java*](http://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Installing_Java).

Comment: The fact that it says `java version "1.5.0"` in that output is pretty suspicious; that's not Java 7.

Answer (score 1):

I posted the same answer in [android studio 135.1339820 launches wrong java version on openSuse 12.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346152/android-studio-135-1339820-launches-wrong-java-version-on-opensuse-12-3)

I resolved this problem by adding this line in the studio.sh
"JDK_HOME=/usr/java/latest"

```
 #!/bin/sh
 #
 # ---------------------------------------------------------------------
 # Android Studio startup script.
 # ---------------------------------------------------------------------
 #

 JDK_HOME=/usr/java/latest
 ...
```

you should replace "/usr/java/latest" with your java location if not here.

Answer (score -2):

You are both partly correct, I forgot to export JDK_HOME :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).