# android studio 135.1339820 launches wrong java version on openSuse 12.3

Tags: java, android

I'm running openSuse 12.3 and have a Java 7-compatible version installed:

```
user@machine:~/saug/android-studio/bin$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

However, when I launch android studio 135.1339820, it launches java 1.5.0 and therefore fails:

```
user@machine:~/saug/android-studio/bin$ ./studio.sh 
java version "1.5.0"
gij (GNU libgcj) version 4.7.2 20130108 [gcc-4_7-branch revision 195012]

Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.swing.UIManager
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.13)
   at javax.swing.UIManager.getUI(libgcj.so.13)
   at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.updateUI(libgcj.so.13)
   at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.<init>(libgcj.so.13)
   at javax.swing.JEditorPane.<init>(libgcj.so.13)
   at javax.swing.JTextPane.<init>(libgcj.so.13)
   at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:237)
   at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:224)
   at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:87)
```

Is there a way to specify which java version (or path) to use?
Thanks

Comment: Check the studio.sh file which java version is grabbing.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by adding this line in the studio.sh
"JDK_HOME=/usr/java/latest"

```
 #!/bin/sh
 #
 # ---------------------------------------------------------------------
 # Android Studio startup script.
 # ---------------------------------------------------------------------
 #

 JDK_HOME=/usr/java/latest
 ...
```

you should replace "/usr/java/latest" with your java location if not here.